# É possível ler uma string que contem um rtf a partir do Report Server Project do Visual Studio (C#)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, relatório, reportviewer, crystal-reports

Visual Studio (C#) Report Server Project SSRS

Possuo uma string que contem um rtf (é um contrato) e gostaria de recebela por parametro no Report Server Project do Visual Studio 2022 e exibir na tela o relátorio para que o usuário possa imprimir, e se possivel no formato .pdf.

No entanto, eu não conheço algum componente que seja capaz de exibir as informações formatadas como no acontece no Windows Forms ou no ASP.NET.

Como recebo uma string com os dados do rtf não será necessário conectar ao banco de dados.

Pesquisei e encontrei pessoas que tentaram, mas sem retorno de se conseguiram.

Será que é posivel fazer isto?

iniciei o projeto, mas não encontrei componentes capazes de exibir o relátorio de maneira formatada, nem de nenhuma maneira.